# how do i add this php script to my .html page

Tags: facebook

```
<?php
// check for minimum PHP version
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
exit('Sorry, this script does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !');
} else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
// if you are using PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 you have to include the password_api_compatibility_library.php
// (this library adds the PHP 5.5 password hashing functions to older versions of PHP)
require_once('libraries/password_compatibility_library.php');
}
// include the config
require_once('config/config.php');

// include the to-be-used language, english by default. feel free to translate your   project and include something else
require_once('translations/en.php');

// include the PHPMailer library
require_once('libraries/PHPMailer.php');

// load the login class
require_once('classes/Login.php');

// create a login object. when this object is created, it will do all login/logout stuff           automatically
// so this single line handles the entire login process.
$login = new Login();

// ... ask if we are logged in here:
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
// the user is logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
// for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are logged in" view.
include("views/index1.php");

} else {
// the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
// for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in" view.
include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

I am trying to add this .php log in script to a HTML webpage. Me and a buddy managed to get a database together along with .php log in script we have downloaded. Our database works with our our .php allowing new users to sing up and log in. Also has email verification with SMTP. Ebery thing works fine but our issue is that when people would go to the log in page it is just a white page with a username and password box. We would like to take our web template and use that as our log in back ground (so that it wouuld be the same background as rest of site.) we just want our log in pages,registration, and all our other .php files to match our site.

Its just ugly having a plain white screen with 1 box for username and 1 box for password and a submit button. thanks.

I was also told .css would help. My whole site is using a style.css file to give the HTML pages there look. Is there any way to make that work for the .php pages too? again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can include HTML outside of the `<?php` and `?>` tags.  Use the HTML to style your page to your liking.

Comment: so I can Leave the .php file as a .php file but on the scripting of it I can just add HTML scripting to it as long as it is not within the php scripting its self?

Comment: Correct.  You could also put your script in a separate file and just use `<?php include("myLoginScript.php")?>` in the HTML.  Some web servers will require your PHP files actually have the .php extension.

Comment: when I added "include("myLoginScript.php")?> " to my html file it didn't work, it did not pull up the user log in screen.

Comment: This time it didnt give me an error message though, normaly when it dosnt work I get a error message this time I did not. but it didn't work.